# Outgoing email and document publishing workflow

Tags: workflow, email

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 x64 and Windows Server 2008 x64. I have setup a site with the publishing portal template. I have granted anonymous access to all the sites.

I have set some users to be the Approver role. Since during the document publishing workflow, SharePoint workflow needs to send email to approvers, I am wondering how to set the email address of a specific approver? And if the email I set for a specific approver is like john@gmail.com, do I also need to set the SMTP/POP3 server of gmail (if needed, how)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you synchronizing profiles with Active Directory or some other source?
If so, then the email property will be controlled by those sources.

If you are not importing profiles or that property is not in those source, you will need to go into your Shared Service Provider and change the property so that it won't synchronize and be overwritten. Then you can go in and update the property for those users in the Shared Service Provider, or you can have the user do it from their profile page in their My Site.

As for emailing external to your organization, you would have to work with your mail server administrator to set up the ability for the server to relay. I have usually seen this limited to internal email addresses only for security, but you will have to work with them to ensure that you are in compliance with their security guidelines.

Lori

Comment: Thanks Lori, for you mentioned "Shared Service Provider", do you mean Shared Services Administration from SharePoint Central Administation? BTW: for some of my environment, I am using Active Directory, but for other environment, I am not using Active Directory. I am not using mysite. I am interested how to configure email for a user of approver role in environment where Active Directory is not used.

Comment: "set up the ability for the server to relay" -- I am interested in this, could you recommend me some documents to read?

Comment: You can find some information about Relay for Exchange 2007 here: http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2006/12/28/432013.aspx I don't know if you are using Exchange or not, but that would be a good place to start.

If you are not using Active Directory, do you have a SQL database of users? You could add a field or table for Email Address and populate it there. The only other option you could use would be to set up a workflow using SPD where you manually enter the email address.

Comment: For the environment using AD, you can always either use the AD fields or click on the Shared Service Provider from Central Administration (It would say "SharedServices1" or whatever you named it.